# group_by two columns does not work, counting all events instead

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Hej!

I want to group my data by age and Cohort and count the events (event_placeholder) per group so that  can finally plot the results in ggplot. my problem is the step before: my group by summation counts only ALL of the information, not group-wise.

This would be an extract of the data (it has like 10 Cohorts or so):

```
    # A tibble: 184,374 x 7
# Groups:   age, Cohort [707]
   Cohort      id enter  stop event_placeholder   age age_group
   <fctr>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>             <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1   1830 1000067     0     1                 0    15        15
 2   1830 1000067     1     2                 0    16        15
 3   1830 1000067     2     3                 0    17        15
 4   1830 1000067     3     4                 0    18        15
 5   1830 1000067     4     5                 0    19        15
 6   1830 1000067     5     6                 0    20        20
 7   1830 1000067     6     7                 0    21        20
 8   1830 1000067     7     8                 0    22        20
 9   1830 1000067     8     9                 0    23        20
10   1830 1000067     9    10                 0    24        20
# ... with 184,364 more rows
```

The code is here:

## Sum years and events by group

```
Marr_Rates_sums <- group_by(Marr_Rates_split, age, Cohort)

#Marr_Rates_sums$stop <- round(Marr_Rates_sums$stop, digits = 1)
Marr_Rates_sums <- summarise(Marr_Rates_sums,
years = sum(stop-enter),
marriages = sum(event_placeholder),
rate = marriages/years
)
```

and the result:

```
  years         marriages       rate
1 180187.6      6988            0.03878181
```

Why does the code count all the events group and age wise?

Comment: Try `dplyr::summarise(Marr_Rates_sums,`  I think you must have loaded `plyr` which also have `summarise` function

Comment: Marr_Rates_sums <- group_by(Marr_Rates_split, age, Cohort) ceomes before the visualisation of the data frame....

Comment: crazy. you solved it. thanks a lot. i lost 2.5 hours on it...

Comment: Please include the names of any packages that you are using in your question. For example, `group_by` and `summarize` are not base R functions. Reade the first section [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) for tips.